# Service Registry for Apache Camel Applications

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

A registry is a list of items with pointers for where to find the items, like the index on a database table or the card catalog for a library.

Correct me if I am wrong, from this definition, what I'd expect from a camel application registry is where a client application can (depending on the client protocol) do a lookup and based on metadata, selects a particular service and uses it as defined.

I am wondering if Apache Camel has anything close to this. Most of the service registries articles/implementations I have seen seems to address only SOAP protocols.

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the REST API from camel-web to lookup routes and endpoint which is the "services" in Camel.
http://camel.apache.org/web-console.html

In terms of a SOA service registry then you may look at other products which specialize in that such as Apache ZooKepper
http://hadoop.apache.org/zookeeper/

You can use ManagementStrategy SPI to hook into events in Camel and track services as they are created/started/stopped etc. Then you can bridge that to your SOA service registry product of choice.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I were to use the camel web console from ServiceMix ESB, how can I access it?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the CamelContext getEndpoints() and getEndpointsMap() APIs to browse the endpoints

see this post for some general monitoring information...

http://benoday.blogspot.com/2011/01/apache-camel-monitoring.html

Comment: Hi Boday,Have any blog on this?

Comment: here are some quick notes on some options...http://benoday.blogspot.com/2011/01/apache-camel-monitoring.html